# Is there a way to query all tables for a value in Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a way to search for a keyword across all columns of all tables in Azure Data Explorer? I know "* has" syntax works for searching in all columns in a table but if I want to search for a keyword across all tables, how do I do it?

Comment: I have already searched in the Kusto(Azure Data Explorer) documentation but could not find anything..

Answer (score 4):

from an efficiency standpoint, it's better, whenever possible, to scope your query only to the specific table(s) which is (are) relevant to your use case.

that said, you may want to look at the `find` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/findoperator

Answer (score 2):

You can try below option:

`search  in (_*_) "NPA*" or "CSA*"`

Comment: highlight your code chunk with ``` before and after the code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`search`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/search-operator) to look for text in all columns in all tables:

```
search "Kelce"
```

As stated, it's more efficient to specify tables (or columns) to search in:

```
search in (Ravens,Eagles,C*) "Kelce"
```